# Form submit doesn't update model bound to radiobutton

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my HTML:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="submit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio" ng-repeat="answer in answers">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="answer" ng-model="submittedAnswer" value="{{$index}}" /> {{ answer }}
              </label>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Далее</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

And in angular controller I have this code:

```
$scope.submittedAnswer = 0;

$scope.submit = function () {
    answers.push($scope.submittedAnswer);

    console.log($scope.submittedAnswer);
}
```

On submit I'm always getting `0`. It seems that problem only about radiobutton. I've tried to bind model to simple text input and all worked fine. Any suggestions? BTW, is there any way to avoid initializing of model (I don't want any radiobutton to be checked initially)?

Comment: @dfsq, it's data, that I'm getting via `$http.get()` it works fine and renders  HTML as expected: `<input type="radio" name="answer" ng-model="submittedAnswer" value="0" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">`

Comment: You can have ng-click="submit({{$index}})" on the button to pass the value, you dont need a model.

Comment: @Avraam, not working. `submit({{$index}})` is not a valid code and `submit($index)` gives me `undefined`.

Comment: I will write a jsfiddle, give me 5 minutes

Comment: @Avraam, thank you, I'll be waiting.

Comment: Finally works! Simple replacing `$scope.submittedAnswer` with `$scope.formData.submittedAnswer` did it. Have no idea why :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $parent inside the ng-repeat model to bind your model.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myapp.controller('myController', function($scope){

  $scope.answers = ['One','Two','Three'];
  
  $scope.submit = function(){
    console.log($scope.submittedAnswer);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
<form role="form" ng-submit="submit()" ng-init="submittedAnswer = 0">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="radio" ng-repeat="answer in answers">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="answer" ng-model="$parent.submittedAnswer" value="{{$index}}" /> {{ answer }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Далее</button>
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact reading you need to understand why. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance